# Cannot add new column - "Field name already exists"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add a new column to a freshly created list. The list was created through the UI.

Now, when I try to add a new column to it through the UI, I get the following error:

> Field name already exists.
>   The name used for this field is already used by another field in the list.  Select another name and try again.

If i try to add via the Designer, I get the following error:

> Could not save te field changes to the server.

I can create a site column. However, if I try to add it to the list, or its content types, I get the same errors.

I have checked, and there are no conflicting field names. I get the error for any name, even random character sequences.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What's the column name you're adding? What kind of list is it?

Comment: Regular custom list. And the name doesn't mater. I may type in `foo`, `bar`, or even bang my hand against the keyboard like `saljgbwbg` and it'll say a field with that name already exists.

Comment: Are there any custom solutions deployed to the farm? Do any of them contain custom site columns or content types? It could be that there's an issue with some other site column; it's not necessarily an issue with your particular custom (generic) list or the field you're adding. Also, have you checked the ULS logs (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69933/view-uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check the ULS log because this is SharePoint Online. And yes, there are custom site columns and content types.

Comment: is it just this one list, or any list in your site?

Comment: Just this one list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happened because the list was using two site columns which had the same GUID. How this could have happened is beyond me, as well as why SharePoint would allow this.

I removed one of the site columns, which wasn't in use anyway, and now I can add fields to the list just fine. I just wish the error message was more clear on what was really happening.

Comment: I don't know how the hell you figure this out but this fixed the problem for me. You are a rockstar !!!