# How marge SpLogFile by colrelation in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

```
Merge-SPlogfile –Path "Path" –Correlation "id"
```

I know that above command is the way of finding log file in on-premise environment. How can I do this in sharepoint online (office 365). I am getting following error in my site. I am familiar with [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) but no idea about the appropriate command.

[image]

Comment: This thread might be useful. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69933/view-uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no way to get the ULS logs from SharePoint Online. ULS logs are located at server and can be accessed by farm admin. But on SharePoint online we are tenant administrator but not farm.

You can ask / open a service request with SharePoint Online support team and provide them the error details, they will help you.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Contact-Office-365-for-business-support-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b