# Error while clicking the SharePoint Custom List edit form save button

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, office-365, custom-form

I am working on office 365 list custom form (SharePoint designer form).

Here I have a scenario like load other list columns in the drop-down column, I did it using REST API adding jQuery. But while saving the edited form it shows an error and correlation id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try checking logs for that particular correlation ID.

Comment: Its office 365 we can't check log here

Comment: I loaded the Choice fields dropdown dynamically using RestAPI. after selecting any value and trying to save the error occurs

Comment: Is there any error in browser console? If Yes, please add any screenshot or error to your question.

Comment: Any you can get the ULS logs by creating a ticket to support team. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69933/view-uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: No error in Browser console ganesh. this is the only column creating error while saving the form.Should i change any thing in <SharePoint:FormField> custom edit form?

Comment: If you can add the code you used to load other list columns in the drop-down column then that will be helpful to answer your question.