# How to debug error in sharepoint online using Correlation id?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, error, publishing-site, debugging

I have created the sharepoint trial account and i tried to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature in site collection features.But i got error with Correlation id.How can i debug using Correlation id without any powershell scripts?

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365/SharePoint Online you cannot access the ULS logs to lookup the logged information on error situation.

So, the best way is to contact Microsoft Support with the Correlation ID.

However you can get more information using below links:

1. [View uls logs for sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69933/view-uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online)
2. [How to view details of Correlation ID on a SharePoint online site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99493c01-593f-4b73-96f1-a80f3c037909/how-to-view-details-of-correlation-id-on-a-sharepoint-online-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).

Comment: 1) Is possible to get logs using powershell script?
2) This "Sorry something went wrong" issue came at the time of activating "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure". what may be the isue?

Comment: I guess currently there is no way to get the logs using powershell or anything. you need to contact microsoft support team. I am not sure about the feature activation issue. you will get better picture of exact issue after you will get logs from MS support team.

Comment: try activating the feature again. Sometimes that feature just bombs out. Unless you're on a Modern site, in which case Publishing features are not supported and will not work. But yeah, you can't see the logs without MS help.

Comment: Does this answers your question??

Answer (score 0):

Just as Ganesh said, you will need to open a service request with your Correlation ID to further troubleshoot.

For the feature issue, What is the template of the site collection having this issue? Can you reproduce the error in your other site collections?

Is the site collection in Modern or Classic experience? You are unable to do this for various reasons. More information will be helpful for further troubleshooting.